# Insert multiple rows into a table in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Hi I have a the following scenario

```
Table - Items
    id int (PK),
    name varchar(100)

Table - Category
    id int (PK),
    name varchar(100)

Table - Category_item
    category_id int (FK),
    item_id int (FK)
```

I'm using `Asp.Net MVC` and `Entitydatamodel`.
In the view I have a dropdown list to show the categories and a check boxes to display item.

I want to insert into the Table - Category_item when i select the category and curresponding items.
How can i do it? How can I pass the values from the view to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anwser is that it depends. But the general case is (RAZOR)

> @Html.DropDownList(category, 
>                         db.Categories.Select(cat => new
>   SelectListItem()
>                              {Text = cat.Name,
>                               Value = cat.Id,
>                               Selected = (false/true)
>                              }).ToList());

You can use `Html.DropDownListFor` and then the Save action will already be bounded with correct value. 'db' is the model context.

Comment: For Items I cant use dropdown because it is a one - many relation. I'm using checkbox for showing items. How can i get those values in the view?

Comment: In that case you should use `Html.CheckBox("categories", [true/false] , new { value = category.id})` for each category and on the controller side have a parameter named "categories" of type IList<[idtype]> Where idtype is the type of the id e.g. int.